# Material design activity animation onClick event on custome ListView

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-5.0-lollipop

I am currently working on one app which requires fetching data from server and have to display them in  Listview. Fetching and display part is working fine i have used custom listview for that.

Now i want to implement Material design animation to my activity. How do i add this animations to activity same as this. [Material Animation](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/videos/animations-meaningfultransitions-hierarchical_transitions_topLevel_large_xhdpi.webm)

Here is second example, [Material  Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkWI1FKKrs4) i have listView with click event. how to implement such animation using listview.??

I am populating this listView using json feed.

Thank you. any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

album_grid.xml

```
    <ImageView
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_album_cover" />
```

album_details.xml

```
    <ImageView
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_album_cover" />
```

AlbumActivity.java

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String transitionName = getString(R.string.transition_album_cover);
    …
    ActivityOptionsCompat options =
    ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity,
        albumCoverImageView,   // The view which starts the transition
        transitionName    // The transitionName of the view we’re transitioning to
        );
    ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, options.toBundle());
```

Source: http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html

Comment: I have used custom listview to display my json fetched array.  Do you know how can we implement this on listview.?

Comment: Place the Intent intent = new Intent() etc. etc. etc. in your onClick method of your listview item. Then you're able to make an animation with shared elements.

Comment: See also https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions
and go to "Start an activity with a shared element"

Comment: i did same as you have mentioned but its using whole listview to start shared transition. i mean it should start expanding from listview item which is clicked to new activity. @Exaqt